# Getting substring from a matching string in PHP

Tags: php

I want to get sub-string from a string and the sub-string will have a certain format.
Eg :

- `This is my test ABC-MMS-0001`
- `Another test for ABC-MMS-00023`

I need a way to get just the sub string which is in format `ABC-MMS-<anynumber>`

The above example should give me:

- `ABC-MMS-0001`
- `ABC-MMS-00023`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `preg_match` with the pattern `\b\w+-\w+-\d+\b`:

```
$input = "This is my test ABC-MMS-0001";
$matches = array();
preg_match("/\b\w+-\w+-\d+\b/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches)[0];
```

This outputs:

```
ABC-MMS-0001
```